# Way to save/load session to disk

Tags: 19.04

I'm curious if it's possible to save state of running processes and reload them later? Like hibernation but where you can choose which snapshot to load? This would be really helpful when you are working on different projects and you have a ton of stuff you have to open and position on your monitors.

Im sure a solution like this exists out there but i was not able to find it. I did consider running virtualbox and saving workspaces as virtual machines. Currently i'm using ubuntu mate 19.04.

Comment: XFCE has that feature; where you could save a session and choose which to continue when you next logged in.    (https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/start)  but I haven't used it in ages.  Note: it doesn't save processes, but only opened apps/window-positions/workspaces etc.

Comment: XFFE Examples http://users.xfce.org/~kelnos/testing/xfsm-dbus-examples.txt but it does not store data open in programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did consider running virtualbox and saving workspaces as virtual machines

That is the way to do it if you want it working consistently across different desktops: hibernation in a virtual container. This will store anything in memory.

The "save session" got removed from most systems as it was considered a security breach: a "save session" could be used by another user on the same system to view the contents of that session.